# How to call a view from another view in iPhone

Tags: ios4

I want to call a view in the same view on a button click, is there any way to do it other then PushViewContrller and PresentModalView.

Thanx in advance......

Answer (score 1):

i think its working ......

```
-(void)btn_clicked{

[self addSubView:new_View];
  }
```